# openvpn con salida a internet

Tags: vpn

tengo la siguiente configuración y necesito salida a Internet de los clientes:

```
                      +-------------------------+
           (public IP)|                         |
{INTERNET}============{     Router              |
                      |                         |
                      |         LAN switch      |
                      +------------+------------+
                                   | (192.168.0.1)
                                   |
                                   |              +-----------------------+
                                   |              |                       |
                                   |              |        OpenVPN        |  eth0: 192.168.0.186/24
                                   +--------------{eth0    server         |  tun0: 192.168.1.1/24
                                   |              |                       |
                                   |              |           {tun0}      |
                                   |              +-----------------------+
                                   |
                          +--------+-----------+
                          |                    |
                          |  Other LAN clients |
                          |                    |
                          |   192.168.0.0/24   |
                          |   (internal net)   |
                          +--------------------+
```

no he logrado hacer que los clientes tengan salida a internet. Mis configuraciones son las siguientes:

> archivo de servidor VPN

```
port 1194
proto udp
dev tun0
ca keys/changeme/ca.crt
cert keys/changeme/serverjvpn.crt
key keys/changeme/serverjvpn.key
dh keys/changeme/dh2048.pem
server 192.168.1.0 255.255.255.0
crl-verify keys/changeme/crl.pem
cipher BF-CBC
user nobody
group FabMira
status servers/JorpaVPN/logs/openvpn-status.log
log-append servers/JorpaVPN/logs/openvpn.log
verb 6
mute 20
max-clients 100
keepalive 10 120
client-config-dir /etc/openvpn/servers/JorpaVPN/ccd
client-to-client
comp-lzo
persist-key
persist-tun
ccd-exclusive
route 10.10.1.0 255.255.255.0
push "route 192.168.0.0 255.255.255.0"
push "route 10.10.1.0 255.255.255.0"
push "dhcp-option DNS 192.168.0.186"
push "redirect-gateway def1"
```

> archivo de iptables

```
-A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.1.0/24 -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
-A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.0.0/24 -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
-A POSTROUTING -s 10.10.1.0/24 -o tun0 -j MASQUERADE COMMIT
# Completed on Thu May  5 11:27:58 2016
# Generated by iptables-save v1.4.7 on Thu May  5 11:27:58 2016
*filter :FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0] :INPUT ACCEPT [0:0] :OUTPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
-A INPUT -p tcp -m state -m tcp --dport 80 --state NEW -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p udp -m state -m udp --dport 1194 --state NEW -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m state -m tcp --dport 1194 --state NEW -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m state -m tcp --dport 5000 --state NEW -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p udp -m state -m udp --dport 5000 --state NEW -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p udp -m state -m udp --dport 53 --state NEW -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m state -m tcp --dport 22 --state NEW -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m state -m tcp --dport 20 --state NEW -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p icmp -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp -i eth0 --dport 1723 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p gre -i eth0 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-host-prohibited
-A FORWARD -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-host-prohibited
-A FORWARD -i eth0 -o tun0 -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i tun0 -o eth0 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i ppp+ -o eth0 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i eth0 -o ppp+ -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i ppp+ -o eth0 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i eth0 -o ppp+ -j ACCEPT
-I FORWARD -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -s 192.168.1.0/24 -d 192.168.1.0/24 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -s 192.168.1.0/24 -d 192.168.0.0/24 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -s 192.168.0.0/24 -d 192.168.1.0/24 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -s 192.168.0.0/24 -d 192.168.0.0/24 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -s 10.10.1.0/24 -d 10.10.1.0/24 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -s 10.10.1.0/24 -d 192.168.1.0/24 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -s 192.168.1.0/24 -d 10.10.1.0/24 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -s 10.10.1.0/24 -d 192.168.0.0/24 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -s 192.168.0.0/24 -d 10.10.1.0/24 -j ACCEPT
```

que puedo tener malo, por favor ayuda.

Comment: Puede que el hecho que el OpenVPN y el Router usen la misma ip ( 192.168.0.1) tenga algo que ver,

Comment: No sé mucho del tema, pero prueba por descarte , pon todo INPUT Y OUTPUT ACCEPT , y sino es el iptables es el vpn.

Comment: Tengo el mismo problema ¿Cuál fue la solución correcta?, saludos.

Answer (score 2):

No suelo usar openVPN usualmente, pero creo que se cual podría ser tu problema:

Primero pon los DNS de google para la resolución de los DNS:

```
push "dhcp-option DNS 8.8.4.4"
push "dhcp-option DNS 8.8.8.8"
```

Luego configuras el IP forwarding, editando el archivo /etc/sysctl.conf:

```
nano /etc/sysctl.conf
```

Y buscas "net.ipv4.ip_forward" (ctrl+w para buscar en nano) y revisas que quedé así:

```
net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1
```

Obviamente no tiene que tener "#" por delante y si no está en el archivo, debes lo debes agregar, luego ejecuta "sysctl -p" para aplicar los cambios y también reinicia openVPN.